# how to localize kinect in pre_saved pcd map?

Tags: ros, localization, navigation, visual-odometry, ccny-rgbd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been able to successfully install and run ccny_rgbd and save out a pcd map.
I can also see the map using pcd_viewer.
Can someone tell me the steps to then localize the kinect "within" a saved map?
ie. now that I have a map, what are the steps for the kinect to localize within it and once it does, how can I visualize both in rviz?
Thanks,
-Scott

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56535/how-to-localize-kinect-in-pre_saved-pcd-map?/) by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on ROS Answers with karma: 693 on 2013-02-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on 2013-02-27**:
Are there plans to enhance the stack to support navigation in a map that ccny_rgbd has captured? Or is there a way to do this via exporting it as an octomap or some other way you could suggest?

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2013-02-28**:
The support to export an Octomap is there (it's not exported continuously though, you must call a service). We are working on localization, but other navigation features (path-planning, obstacle avoidance) will be outside the scope of this package

**Comment by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on 2013-02-28**:
Thank you for your comments. I was able to export the map as an octomap and will attempt to use that and localize a kinect within it using humanoid_localization stack. Thanks again. the ccny_rgbd is a fantastic package. Good luck.

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2013-02-28**:
No problem, glad you find it useful. If you ever have time, send me a screenshot of your octomap :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the functionality to localize on a pre-existing map does not currently exist in ccny_rgbd, but might exist using other tools

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2013-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0